# Best way to try to recover a failed hard SATA 3.5" drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sata, hard-drive-failure

When I booted my desktop this morning it announced it was scanning and repairing one of my drives.

When it finally booted into Windows, the drive showed up, but when I tried to right click it to bring up properties it did nothing.  I asked the PC to reboot, upon which Windows sat on the "Windows is restarting" screen for about an hour.  Now that it's finally back up the drive is missing.  When I go into Computer Management it says that the drive is unitialised and would I like to initialise it with MBR or GPT (I chose neither).

There's nothing hugely crucial on the drive, but I would like to try to recover it.

What's my best method of attack?  What's the best software to try to tackle this?  I'm happy to pay for some drive recovery software, say up to $100.  Can i do this effectively in Windows 10, or would I be better off creating a linux boot system on a memory stick and working with the drive from there instead?

Any advice appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Best there is.....https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm

Comment: Check SMART statistics to see if it's failing. If it isn't, run CHKDSK to clean up corruption.  Then format and use the drive.  Before using it for anything critical, periodically rerun CHKDSK to verify that it isn't continuing to degrade.  If there are new problems, replace the drive.

Comment: How would I check those, @fixer1234

Comment: For SMART, use a utility that displays the statistics, like [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/), which is free.  For CHKDSK, open a command prompt as administrator, enter `chkdsk /r`, which will analyze physical errors as well as corruption, and accept running it on the next boot.  It can take a long time on a drive of any significant size (hours; the major part of a day if it is a large drive with a lot of problems), and it shouldn't be interrupted once it starts, so plan accordingly.

Comment: Annoyingly after installation CDI doesn't seem to want to launch. Task Manager shows that it's running with 0% CPU and 1.7MB RAM, but even after 10 minutes there's no evidence the application has opened - no windows, no taskbar button, no system tray icon.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems SpinRite is no use.  I'm not entirely surprised when it's not had an update since 2004 - motherboard chipsets, SATA controllers etc have all had a lot of changes in the last 15 years!  Sadly in my case it crashes with a division overflow error every time I try to run it at level 2 or above.

Comment: If the drive is spinning, you MIGHT be able to get data off of it, but you'll usually still be able to manipulate the drive in Disk Management at that point. If the drive is not spinning physical recovery is your only hope, and that costs big bucks. Personally, I've used GetDataBack and found it to be one of the best data recovery tools so long as the drive is physically still working.